# Compilation Error Using QuickDialog in a Swift iOS project

Tags: ios, swift, quickdialog

I am new to iOS. I am trying to use QuickDialog in an iOS project. Following is my podfile content

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '7.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!

target 'MyLife' do
pod 'QuickDialog', '~> 1.0'
pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.23.3'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.8'
end

target 'MyLifeTests' do

end
```

I have written the MyLife-Bridhing-Header.h file and imported QuickDialog in it. And QuickDialog is now accessible in my swift codes. But when I try to build the project, 6 compilation errors occur all of which are related to QuickDialog.

[image: compilation errors]

I have also tried writing a Prefix header (.pch) file with the content

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <QuickDialog/QuickDialog.h>
```

I have set this file as the Prefix Header in Build settings. But the errors remained. What am I doing wrong here? Please help.

Comment: QuickDialog is kind of old for Swift I think and if you are new on iOS I would recommend you to use the good and nice ```UITableView```.

Comment: @eduardo-scoz  can you please have a look if you have time?